# AWS EC2 CLI -> How to get list of avaliable instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Good day time, profs.
I am a bit new to aws cli framework. What i need to get via console is a list of available instances in a specified region with a limit number of that type.

For example, command should look like:

```
aws ec2 describe-available-instances --region us-west-1 --type [t1.micro, c3.4xlarge, etc. If not set - list all types]
```

and the output will look like:

---

t1.micro 5

c3.4xlarge 10

m4.4x 20

---

Comment: What is an "available" instance?

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve this output as JSON with AWS CLI and [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

### Step by step:

1) Call the describe-instances command.  This retrieves all sorts of metadata about an EC2 Instance, including the Instance Type. We will eventually filter our output down to Instance Type alone.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

2) Specify an instance-type filter via the `--filter` param.  If this is not specified, this query will display all instance types where count > 0. This will not include 0-count types because the output is derived from your collection of EC2 instances.

```
--filters "Name=instance-type,Values=t2.micro,t2.small"
```

3) Specify a region via the `--region` param. If this is not specified, AWS CLI will attempt to use your default region.

```
--region us-east-1
```

4) Specify your query.  Output an array of key/value pairs where Key = "InstanceType", Value = InstanceType.

```
--query "Reservations[].Instances[].{InstanceType:InstanceType}"
```

5) Use jq to group by Instance Type, so that like-InstanceTypes will be aggregated.

```
| jq "group_by(.InstanceType)
```

6) Map a final array of key/value pairs, where key = InstanceType and value = `jq length`, or in other words the sum of each group of instance types.

```
| map({(.[0].InstanceType):length})
```

### Full Example:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --filters "Name=instance-type,Values=t2.micro,t2.small" --query "Reservations[].Instances[].{InstanceType:InstanceType}" | jq "group_by(.InstanceType) | map({(.[0].InstanceType):length})"
```

### Output:

```
[
  {
    "t2.micro": 12
  },
  {
    "t2.small": 2
  }
]
```

---

### Additional Notes

If you're trying to retrieve the Amazon GameLift per-instance-type limits, use describe-ec2-instance-limits:

```
aws gamelift describe-ec2-instance-limits --query 'EC2InstanceLimits[].{EC2InstanceType:EC2InstanceType,InstanceLimit:InstanceLimit}' --region us-east-1 --output text
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - aws gamelift describe-ec2-instance-limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/gamelift/describe-ec2-instance-limits.html)
- [AWS Documentation - aws ec2 describe-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)
- [AWS Documentation - Controlling Command Output from the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)
- [JQ - Builtin operators and functions](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions)

Comment: Thank you so much, clever smarty Anthony, that's best answer i got in my entire life !!! That's exactly what i needed. What can i do for you in return for such a great, huge, explicit answer ? I was also thinking on an issue to collect that data in array, but your answer already has that!!!! Awesome

Comment: Heh, thanks. :) You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of this post if it resolved your issue. This will also note to others that the question has been resolved. Keep learning and growing and asking questions!

Answer (score 9):

With purpose see all instances without filters - use this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text \
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceType]' | sort | uniq -c
```

Output will look like this:

```
1 m3.medium
1 m4.10xlarge
9 m4.xlarge
6 t2.large
5 t2.medium
4 t2.micro
2 t2.xlarge
```

And with purpose to filter by specific type - just add filter, like this: 
`--filters "Name=instance-type,Values=t2.micro,t2.small"`, your comand will look like this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text \
--filters "Name=instance-type,Values=t2.micro,t2.small" \
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceType]' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Worked pretty well! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar requirement as above, but also wanted to filter on ***running*** ***instances*** and view the results per region (**sorted**).

Using some of the awesome responses from @Vladimir-Kovpak, and @ Anthony Neace, I ended up with this, may help someone (those guys helped me)

```
for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions --query 'Regions[].RegionName | sort(@)' --output text); \
do echo $region; \
    aws ec2 describe-instances \
        --region "${region}" \
        --filter Name=instance-state-name,Values=running \
        --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{InstanceType:InstanceType}' \
        | jq -r '.[].InstanceType' \
        | sort \
        | uniq -c \
        | sort -r;
done
```

... resulting in output similar to below...

```
ap-northeast-1
ap-northeast-2
ap-south-1
ap-southeast-1
   5 m3.medium
   4 m4.xlarge
   3 t2.micro
   2 t2.large
   2 t2.medium
   2 m3.large
   1 t2.xlarge
   1 t2.small
   1 m4.large
ap-southeast-2
   5 t2.medium
   4 m4.xlarge
   3 t2.micro
   2 t2.large
   2 m3.medium
   2 m3.large
   1 t2.xlarge
   1 t2.small
   1 m4.large
ca-central-1
eu-central-1
eu-west-1
eu-west-2
eu-west-3
sa-east-1
us-east-1
us-east-2
us-west-1
us-west-2
```

Also, to save having to paste this in each time, I added it to my aws alias file. Run on the cli with:

```
aws all
```

Example below. (create at $HOME/.aws/cli/alias)
See the [aws cli alias github](https://github.com/awslabs/awscli-aliases) repo for details (and more great time saving aliases)

```
# Add to your existing, or create this file at $HOME/.aws/cli/alias

[toplevel]


# Run, with 'aws who'
who = sts get-caller-identity

# Run, with 'aws all'

all = ! 
  ! g() {
    for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions --query 'Regions[].RegionName | sort(@)' --output text); \
    do echo $region; \
      aws ec2 describe-instances \
          --region "${region}" \
          --filter Name=instance-state-name,Values=running \
          --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{InstanceType:InstanceType}' \
          | jq -r '.[].InstanceType' \
          | sort \
          | uniq -c \
          | sort -r;
        done
      }; g
```